# Test WebRTC video call application

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, webrtc

I made a video chat application in WebRTC and its working properly using node js server. How can I use other devices(phone, laptops) to connect to this server using wifi ?

Comment: can you please share your code or project, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can test also from localhost, launching 2 browser instances. Otherwise just setup proper port forwarding on your router (or set your PC as DMZ)